# Initial func in 1st view from 2nd view (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a button on 2nd `viewController`, after pressing that button, I would like to dismiss the 2nd `viewController` and go back to the 1st view controller and immediately call a **function** that coded inside 1st `ViewController` swift file.

May I know how can I do that? By segue?

Comment: You can set 1st viewcontroller is delegate property of 2nd view controller. When press button, call delegate function to 1st viewcontroller

Comment: When the second view controller is presented pass a closure as a callback and call the closure in the `IBAction`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to do this one of the best way is using `protocol` and `delegate`.

You can create one `protocol` and extend that protocol in your `ViewController1`. Now create the `delegate` of protocol in `ViewController2` and pass reference of that delegate in the `ViewController1's` `prepareForSegue` method.

First create one protocol like this

```
protocol PassdataDelegate {

    func passData()
}
```

Now extend this protocol in `ViewController1` like this and pass the reference of delegate in `prepareForSegue` method

```
class ViewController1 : UIViewController, PassdataDelegate {


    func passData() {
        //Here call your function 
        self.callMyFunction()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifier") {
             let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
             destVC.delegate = self 
        }
    }
}
```

Now create the delegate object of `protocol`in `ViewController2` like this

```
class ViewController2 : UIViewController {

    var delegate: PassdataDelegate?

    //Now call the method of this delegate in Button action
    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
         self.delegate.passData()
         //Now dismiss the controller
    }
}
```

**Note: -** Here i am passing `string`but you can pass any type of object that you have declare in your `delegate` method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but if i just want to dismiss the 2nd view and calling a func in 1st view without passing any string? How can i change the code above?

Comment: I have edited my answer added that delegate method in `ViewController1`, now call your method in delegate method.

Comment: Thanks, That's very helpful indeed.

Comment: Welcome mate Happy Coding :)

Comment: I got the following error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" When i passing the func from ViewController2 to ViewController1. What's happening? My func is just Print("test")

Comment: Can you update the question with new code and on which line you are getting `unexpectedly found nil` error.

Comment: Sorry Problem fixed, silly mistakes on the storyboard.

Comment: @Clarence Its Ok it happens

Comment: This kind of implementation cause the second view controller depend on the implementation of the first controller. And take so many code to do a simple task. I suggest using `unwind segue` because it is designed to do such kind of task.

Comment: @Nirav thank you. Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow. Just want to tell the owner of this answer/and others who will read this thread about a better implementation that is provided by Cocoa Touch. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer `unwind segue`.

```
class ViewController1 {
  @IBAction func doSomeStuffAfterReload(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // do whatever you need to do here.
  }
}
```

On storyboard, from ViewController2 Ctrl+Drag from the `button` to the `exit outlet` and select `doSomeStuffAfterReload`.

You can see it in action here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/
Happy coding^^